# useEffect not rendering before getting to return

Tags: reactjs

**My State**

```
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
```

**GetUser()**

```
    async function getUser() {
         verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL); /* Updates field in backend from false -> true */
         await Axios.get(URL+getTokenIdFromURL).then(function (response) {
         setIsEnabled(response.data.enabled) /* Checks if updated value is true and updates state */
        })
    }
```

**UseEffect()**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
        return () => {
            /* */
        };
    }, []);
```

**Return**

```
    return (
       <div className="emailVerificationWrapper">
        {isEnabled ? <h1>true</h1> : <EmailVerificationFailed /> }
       </div>
    )
```

**Return** is rendered before the **`setIsEnabled`** which causes the final result to be `false`, but if i reload the website(or console log the state value), it is set to `true`(as desired).

> How can i make the `setIsEnabled` to update the state before my applications renders the `return`?

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is run, post your render return statement. You need to have a loading state to wait till the data is fetched

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    return () => {
        /* */
    };
}, []);

function getUser() {
     verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL); /* Updates field in backend from false -> true */
     Axios.get(URL+getTokenIdFromURL).then(function (response) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsEnabled(response.data.enabled) 
    })
}
if(isLoading) {
   return <div>Loading...</div>
}
return (
   <div className="emailVerificationWrapper">
    {isEnabled ? <h1>true</h1> : <EmailVerificationFailed /> }
   </div>
)
```

Comment: This doesnt change anything? The outcome is the same. It displays false until i reload the page.

Comment: @Arasto, are you sure you . API call is a success. Also if you can create a demo it will be easier to figure out the issue

Comment: @Arasto Are you updating something on the server using a get request?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm trying to create a codepen, moment please.
@HMR The `verifyEmail` function is a post method using Axios, which updates the field.

Comment: @Arasto Then maybe you should try `await verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL);` or have verifyEmail return a value indicating it's verified or not and saving you one request.

Comment: @HMR I believe that is the best approach to this issue. I will give this an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Please update like this:

```
async function getUser() {
         verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL); /* Updates field in backend from false -> true */
         const response = await Axios.get(URL+getTokenIdFromURL)
         setIsEnabled(response.data.enabled) /* Checks if updated value is true and updates state */

    }
```

Comment: i did, thank you. The outcome remains the same though.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(async () => {
        await getUser();
        return () => {
            /* */
        };
    }, []);
```

Comment: This doesn't work useEffect doesn't accept async functions

Comment: Async functions return a promise, effect functions are not allowed to return anything but undefined or a function. Did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data
Please check this

Comment: Can you just try it in an app and see it doesn't work. Posting someones blog doesn't make it any better. This also doesn't solve OP's problem that render is not waiting for result. First because it would not wait, that's not how promises work and second the effect would execute after the component rendered anyway.

Comment: @JikunL I see that [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks) points to that same blog but at the same time when you run the code you'll get a warning as soon as you return something from the async effect function.